# Axios does not refresh current token in JWT Auth

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, axios, jwt

I have an axios configuration:

```
import axios from 'axios'
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1'
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
```

but the problem with this line

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')`
```

is that it is not dynamic, if I set it once, it does'nt refresh when the token changes.
What i mean is that:

1. I log to the app, get the token for user 1 and then store it and use it for Auth
2. If i change the account for user2, and log in with user 2 account, get the new token and it is stored in localStorage, i still send request with user1 token in header.

So i figured out how to force it in frontend:

```
async function setToken() {
  const tokenInStorage = localStorage.getItem('token')
  if (tokenInStorage !== null) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${tokenInStorage}`
    const response = await userStore.getFullCredentials()
    console.log(response.data)
  } else {
    alert('theres no token!')
  }
}
```

but I don't think that

```
 axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${tokenInStorage}`
```

should be a part of script of vue comp. But if i deleted it, the Axios sends request with old token. How to solve it?

Comment: headers.common['Authorization'] - this is commonly done in axios interceptor. And token data is commonly stored in global store, LS shouldn't be the single source of truth because it's not reactive in terms of vue

Comment: there's a VueUse composable for [reactive local storage](https://vueuse.org/core/useLocalStorage/) if needed